# QLPreviewController in Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, qlpreviewcontroller

I want to open PDF files using `QLPreviewController` in Monotouch, but I can't to do this.

`QLPreviewItem` is an abstract class, but object of this type returns method :

`QLPreviewControllerDataSource.GetPreviewItem(QLPreviewController, int)`

Anybody has worked example of `QLPreviewController` in Monotouch?

Comment: The same question was sent **and answered** on the MonoTouch mailing-list. See http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2011-December/007079.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subclass QLPreviewItem, and then return 
object from GetPreviewItem:

```
public class QlItem : QLPreviewItem 
{ 
    string title; 
    Uri uri; 

    public QlItem (string title, Uri uri) 
    { 
            this.title = title; 
            this.uri = uri; 
    } 

    public override string ItemTitle { 
            get { return title; } 
    } 

    public override NSUrl ItemUrl { 
            get { return uri; } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least on Cocoa Touch, it is sufficient to return an `NSURL` object in the  data source method (`QLPreviewControllerDataSource.GetPreviewItem()` on mono touch - `previewController: previewItemAtIndex:` on cocoa touch).

`NSURL` already implements `QLPreviewItem`. So unless you want to do fancy stuff, you don't need to subclass/implement `QLPreviewItem`.